# Concatenating n with n + 1

Tags: code-golf, sequence

### Introduction

[OEIS sequence A127421](https://oeis.org/A127421) is the sequence of numbers whose decimal expansion is a concatenation of 2 consecutive increasing non-negative numbers. Put simply, every number in the sequence is formed by putting together *n* with *n+1* for some non-negative, integer value of *n*. The first several terms are:

> 1, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 910, 1011, 1112, 1213, 1314, 1415,
>   1516, 1617, 1718, 1819, 1920, 2021, 2122, 2223, 2324, 2425, 2526,
>   2627, 2728, 2829, 2930, 3031, 3132, 3233, 3334, 3435, 3536, 3637,
>   3738, 3839, 3940, 4041, 4142, 4243, 4344, 4445, 4546, …

### Challenge

Given a single positive integer *n*, print the first *n* entries of OEIS sequence A127421 in increasing order.

- Input and output can be in [any acceptable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Strings or numbers are fine for output.
- Leading zeroes are **not** permitted.
- Either a full program or function is permitted.
- For the purposes of this challenge, *n* will be positive and under 100.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed by default.
- This question is code golf, so lowest byte-count wins.
- Here is some sample input and output:

  ```
  1 => 1
  2 => 1, 12
  3 => 1, 12, 23
  10 => 1, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 910
  ```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask. Good luck.

*P.S this is my first challenge, so hopefully this all makes sense.*

*EDIT: Removed output restriction to allow numbers or strings.*

Comment: Can it be 0 indexed?

Comment: @Jo King No. 1 should refer to the first iteration of the sequence as per the challenge spec.

Comment: No-one's said it yet, but welcome to PPCG! Nice first question, not too hard, yet not completely trivial either, and there's a number of different approaches

Comment: @Jo King Thanks, I'm glad you liked it.

Comment: Do the outputs have to be in order? Can we mix strings and numbers?

Comment: Can the output be space-separated?

Comment: @xnor, yes, they have to be in order. You can mix strings and numbers freely, and space separated is fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŻVƝ
```

A monadic link accepting an integer which yields a list of integers

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7rBjc////29iBgA)**

#### How?

```
ŻVƝ - Link: integer       e.g. 59
Ż   - zero-range               [0,1,2,3,4,5,6, ... ,58,59]
  Ɲ - apply to each pair: i.e: [0,1] or [5,6]  or  [58,59]
 V  -   evaluate* jelly code   1     or 56     or  5859
    -                       -> [1,12,23,45,56, ... 5859]

* When given a list V actually joins the Python string values and evaluates that
  ...so e.g.: [58,59] -> ['58','59'] -> '5859' -> 5859
```

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 32 bytes

```r
strtoi(paste0((x=1:scan())-1,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikqCQ/U6Mgsbgk1UBDo8LW0Ko4OTFPQ1NT11CnQlPzv@l/AA)

Outgolfed by [MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168020/67312), so go upvote that answer!

Comment: There’s been an edit to allow strings... no need for strtoi!

Comment: @JayCe it's necessary to strip the leading `0` from the first output.

Comment: couldn't you remove the leading zero by ending with `[-1]`rather than using `strtoi` or does that fail in some edge case or other?

Comment: @JDL `strtoi` is being used to convert from `"01"` to `1` because `paste0` will return `c("01","12","23","34",...)` and we aren't allowed to return `"01"`.

Comment: You can do the highly inelegant combine to match MickyT's 29, but I'm not a fan. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P1nDUKcgsbgk1UBDo8LWyKo4OTFPQ1NT11CnQlPzv@l/AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar unfortunately that will fail for input of `1`

Comment: @Giuseppe You say "unfortunately"... It's always the edge cases that get me, good catch.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:1//n or f'{f(n-1)} {n-1}{n}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYtBCoAgFAXXdYq3U8FQcyd0GCMkob4ibkI8u7magWHyV@9EdoxwPP49Lw9yRilCKgisBU6bER1tojfqbIQZCJFgJHYJK2H0NO3WJZdIlc9FiPED)

Comment: Never thought `f-strings` can be used for golfing! Nice idea.

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```hs
f n=("":)>>=zipWith(++)$show<$>[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz1ZDSclK087OtiqzIDyzJENDW1tTpTgjv9xGxS7aUE8vL/Z/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoKhwX8A)

Thanks to [Cat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/cat-wizard) for a byte!

Comment: As far as golfing goes you can also use `<$>` as a substitute for `map`, that can be infixed.

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```perl6
{(^$_ Z~1..$_)X+0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1ojTiVeIarOUE9PJV4zQtug9n9xYqVCmoahgYGm9X8A)

Anonymous code block that zips the range 0 to n-1 with 1 to n using the concatenation operator, then adds 0 to every element to force it to a number and remove leading 0s.

Answer (score 7):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 19 bytes

```
I.1.W)>OSo;u.uO;@!-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/99Tz1AvXNPOPzjfulSv1N/aQVH3/39DAwA)

This wraps onto the cube as follows

```
    I .
    1 .
W ) > O S o ; u
. u O ; @ ! - .
    . .
    . .
```

[Watch It Run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIEkgLgogICAgMSAuClcgKSA+IE8gUyBvIDsgdQouIHUgTyA7IEAgISAtIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=MTAK&speed=20)

Got a little room to play with yet, but at the moment

- `W` redirect to the top face heading down
- `I1>` set up the stack with the input and 1 then redirect into the main loop
- `OSo;u` output the top of stack, add space to stack, output, remove and uturn
- `-!@;Ou)` subtract TOS from input, if 0 halt else pop result, output TOS, uturn and increment TOS.  Back into the main loop.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

An extra byte thanks to @Giuseppe

```r
10^nchar(n<-1:scan())*(n-1)+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/39AgLi85I7FII89G19CqODkxT0NTU0sjT9dQUzsPKPsfAA)

A mostly mathematical solution, except for using `nchar()` rather than `floor(log10())`.  I was really surprised that it came in shorter than the [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167836/31347) version.

Comment: [29 bytes!](https://tio.run/##K/r/39AgLi85I7FII89G19CqODkxT0NTU0sjT9dQUzsPKPsfAA) nice work on this, I never would have thought of it!

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks for the extra byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @FrownyFrog*

```apl
(⍎⍕,∘⍕1∘+)¨⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OApMaj3r5HvVN1HnXMAFKGQEpb89CKR72b//9PUzDkSlMwBmJDAwA)

Comment: Wow, our answers tied

Comment: @Zacharý yours is more APLish though :)

Comment: Save 1: ``(⍎⍕,∘⍕1∘+)¨⍳``

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n-1and f(n-1)+[`n-1`+`n`]or[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYuxCoAgFAB3v@KNigW@RqEvMUHDLKGeIi59vbk0HHfLlbddmZYe121w@2cPHkjTjJ4CRD5CSOOGnHTkbK4GbY@5QoJEUD2dB8cJldBQaqI2niQY@xuVEv0D)

Recursive function that returns a mixed list of strings and integers

Comment: Did you intend to edit out the original description "Anonymous function that returns a list"?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Oopsie, fixed! Thanks

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but this doesn't seem to have '12' as the second element.

Comment: @ElPedro That can be fixed by saving a byte with `n and`

Comment: It's not often that a fix saves bytes :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 25 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>--n?f(n)+','+n+-~n:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1k5XN88@TSNPU1tdR107T1u3Ls/K8H9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqGmpjUXqpARppAxppChAVDsPwA)

Comment: `f=n=>--n?[f(n),n]+-~n:1`

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
⟦s₂ᶠcᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9icmFjaHlsb2cy///in6Zz4oKC4bagY@G1kP//MTD/Wg)

#### Explanation

```
⟦         Range: [0, …, Input]
 s₂ᶠ      Find all substrings of length 2
    cᵐ    Map concatenate
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
f n="1":[show=<<[i-1,i]|i<-[2..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz1bJUMkqujgjv9zWxiY6U9dQJzO2JtNGN9pITy8vNvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoKhwX8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Blossom](https://github.com/IMP1/blossom), 88 bytes

```
rule e<int x>[1(x)]=>[1(x-1),2(str(x)+str(x+1))];rule c[1(0)]=>[];e!c
```

Blossom is a graph programming language I'm working on. It can only take graphs as inputs, so this programme expects a graph comprising a single node with its label an integer. It returns a graph of connected edges to form the closest to an array I can get, and the resultant graph is printed to output.

An unminified version of the code is this:

```
rule expand <int x>
    [ 1 (x) ]
 => [ 1 (x-1), 2(str(x)+str(x+1)) ]
where x > 0;

rule clean
    [ 1 (0) ]
 => [];

expand! clean
```

It defines two rules: one called `expand`, which (while there is a node with an integer-valued label in the current graph) creates another node with its increment concatenated, and lowers the value.
This rule also has the condition that x is greater than 0.

The `!` executes this rule for as long as it can be applied on the graph, so in this case it will execute until x is 0. And then the `clean` rule removes this 0 node.

Blossom was not made for golfing, but it doesn't do too badly, I don't think., considering what it is.
There currently isn't really an easy way for people to test blossom code (and the interpreter I'm working on at the moment is not quite finished and a little buggy), but this isn't exactly a competing entry!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>55 48 47</s> 43 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n-1and f(n-1)+[f"{n-1}{n}"]or[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcexCoAgEADQ3a84nDwq8GgL@hJpMOpKqFOkJcJvt5a299J97VH6Wnk8/DkvHmSQjrwswOYDNo7186E8UvQUs6OpcswQIAhkL9tqqCWLQ8pBLsMmICr1h6xFrC8)

Recursive function that takes an integer and returns a mixed list of strings and numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>44</strike> 43 bytes

```c
f(i){i--&&printf(" %2$d%d"+5*!f(i),i+1,i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYk9DsIgFIB3TvGstgEKRkycanoR44Ag7UsqNYhdmp4dYXT7fowcjEl79Gb62idcP9HifBx78pcmfOSWHEW2opRN8w7oo6MV1OeDrW3VXviuXIGtEsi6LeUPL42eFtBhMMKMOgDnmRcGKwFAR8voFYNMccaiy03dGevIlpI6/QA)

Comment: @DLosc The `%m$` format specifier "denotes the position in the argument list of the desired argument, indexed starting from 1" [(`printf(3)` man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). It's pretty handy as long as your C library supports it!

Comment: Thanks... but I'm still confused why `%d%d` (and switching the order of the arguments) doesn't work. (I tried it, but don't know why it produces no output.)

Comment: @DLosc If you change the format string, make sure to change the offset after it (e.g. `" %d%d"` should have `+3*!f(i)`; otherwise, the +5 offset points to the NUL at the end of the string.)

Comment: Oh, okay--I finally get it: the "#2, then #1" is necessary because in the base case, the shortened format string becomes just "#1" and so you need the first printf argument to be `i+1`, not `i`. Very interesting.

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxLDoIwEIb3c4qx2qbVYnwsMd6FtCCTwEBs0QXBq9fC7vufrng5l1Kjycyk1Pgmjo0WKL28Hbw43Y@7NbNkqShMuaQ9sesmX@MjRE/DuX0C5A30FbH@DOQNzICYLeQSMn1b6mr9C67ifCy9sKjYGFxbiI1mU240TjFoITa1wJKulz8) abusing undefined behaviour in the form of unsequenced modification and access to `i`.

Answer (score 3):

### [Shakespeare](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/), 703 bytes

```
Q.Ajax,.Ford,.Act I:.Scene I:.[enter Ajax and Ford]Ford:Open mind!Scene V:.Ajax:You is the sum of thyself the sum of myself the sum of a big bad fat old red pig a big bad fat old lie!Ford:Open mind!Is you nicer zero?Ajax:If so, you is twice the sum of the sum of twice thyself twice thyself thyself!If so,Let us Scene V!Ford:You a cat!Open heart!Scene X:.Ajax:You is the sum of thyself a pig!Is you worse than a cat?If so,let us Scene C.Remember thyself.You is the sum of the sum of a big old red cute rich cat a big old red cute joy a big old pig!Speak mind!You is a big old red cute rich cat!Speak mind!Recall!Ford:Open heart!You is the sum of thyself a joy!Open heart!Let us Scene X.Scene C:.[exeunt]
```

[try it here](https://tio.run/##hVJBasMwEPzK@m4E7dGXEAIFQ6E0gZJScpDldaNElowkk7ifdyVLoXIS0ou83llmZkcynRjHd7I80HNOXpSuc7JkFsqCbBhK9MUXSosa/AhQWYOf2vmjeOtQQstlnYXhj2IiKj5VD9yA3SOYvgXVuHIwKJq01d50KFT8GypaQ0MtKFGDxho617tFBMfsykNpYHDCkjPn9ge1WkxmygaMyifIezo5eO7sr4xYNDb/C98ssL2ihd5A3DoY8UtTYNRmk6U9Um1jLtt/c6F@zcsGJ6WNV6YyEC6CqEhFV2SNLbaVWzVykHvsV9leMmW9RdCc7T39PeyghqTtvW06pMcQdBR6QJlOr5FRIZLLCsk8ysKppyHO0t7Gh7nyD/OMvbS7cXx@@gU)

### ungolfed version

```
127421th Night.
Ajax, likes to read the stars.
Ford, someone Ajax can always count on.
Act I:.
Scene I: Ajax reads a star.
[enter Ajax and Ford]
Ford: Open your mind! 
Scene V: Ford counts what ajax has learned.
Ajax: you are the sum of thyself and the sum of myself and the sum of a big bad fat old red pig and a big bad fat old lie!
Ford: Open Your mind! Are you nicer than zero?
Ajax: If so, you are twice the sum of the sum of twice thyself and twice thyself and thyself! 
If so, Let us Scene V!
Ford: You are a cat! Open your heart!

Scene X: Ajax and Ford recall the nights.
Ajax: You are the sum of thyself and a pig! Are you worse than a cat? If so, Let us Scene C.
Remember thyself. 
You are the sum of the sum of a big old red cute rich cat and a big old red cute joy and a big old pig! 
Speak you mind!
You are a big old red cute rich cat! Speak your mind! Recall your finest hour!
Ford: Open your heart! You are the sum of thyself and a joy! Open your heart! Let us Scene X.
Scene C: Fin.
[exeunt]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```
{(0..<it)*.with{""+it+++it as int}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/J9m@79aw0BPzyazRFNLrzyzJKNaSUk7s0RbG0goJBYrZOaV1Nb@LygC0jl5Cmkappr/AQ)

I came up last minute with the idea of using *.with instead of .collect. I have no idea what `it+++it` parses to but whether it's `it++ + it` or `it + ++it` they both do the same thing. I tried to think of a way of getting rid of the < in ..< by turning it into 1..it and decrementing but I don't think it would get any shorter.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG; nice first post! Regarding the parsing of `a+++b`, [this test](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/M69EIVHBVsFARyEJRHEVFAGFcvIUErW1tZMQPDgr6f9/AA) suggests it is parsed from left to right, meaning `(a++)+b`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
ms+`dh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P7dYOyEFSJsAAA)

Explanation:

```
       - implicit output
m      - map function with argument d:
  +    -  concatenate
    d  -  argument d
   `   -  to string
     h -  into implicit d + 1
       - into Q (implicit input)
```

Comment: Welcom to PPCG! :)

Comment: @Shaggy Thank you, this is my first time doing this.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$8\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 6.585 bytes

```
Mrx'_Jx}
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJNcngnX0p4fSIsIjIiXQ==)

```
Mrx'_Jx}
Mrx'     # For every number in the range [0, input)
       } # Input + 1
     Jx  # Prepend the input to that
    _    # Parse as number to remove leading 0s
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `1` - leading zeros aren't allowed. (Also, the challenge does say to output the first n terms...)

Comment: @Steffan but it is tagged [tag:sequence], so therefore the i/o defaults are allowed?

Comment: the i/o defaults are not allowed if the question overrides them. they are defaults, not requirements

Comment: @Steffan oof. done

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ḶżRV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm1H9wSF/f//39AUAA)

#### How it works

```
ḶżRV  Main link. Argument: n

Ḷ     Unlength; yield [0, ..., n-1].
  R   Range; yield [1, ... n].
 ż    Zipwith; yield [[0, 1], ..., [n-1, n]].
   V  Eval; cast each array to string and evaluate, yielding integers.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
for i in range(input()):print`i`*(i>0)+`i+1`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VIzOvoLREQ1PTqqAoM68kITNBSyPTzkBTOyFT2zDh/39jAwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-m`, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ó2 ¬n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BmI4VDa/L@/9fN5TIyAAA)

As always, *know the flags*.

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
-m       Convert to range and map...

Uó2 q n
Uó2      Construct [U, U+1]
    q    Join
      n  Convert to number

         Implicit output (Array is printed as comma-delimited values)
```

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BmI4VDa/L@/9fN5TIyAAA). Don't know why `ó` doesn't work here without the `2`.

Comment: I have 2 other 5 byte solutions (both using the same method) that don't use a flag, if anyone else wants to take a stab at them.

Comment: I think 5 + 2 = 7 bytes because of flag?

Comment: @u_ndefined [Flags are no longer counted towards bytes, and treated as different implementation.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/78410)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
>GNJ,N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzt3PS8fv/39DAwA)

**Explanation**

```
>G       # for N in [1 ... input]
  N      # push N
   J     # join stack
    ,    # print
     N   # push N (for next iteration)
```

`LεD<ìï` would work for same byte count but with list output

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
1,2,/⍕¨∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CYb/00CkjpGO/qPeqYdWPOqY8ah38///aQqGBgA)

Comment: Nice job, I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
1.."$args"|%{"$p$_";$p=$_}
```

-1 byte: thanks [AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42963/admborkbork)

Test script:

```
$f = {
1.."$args"|%{"$p$_";$p=$_}
}

&$f 1
""
&$f 2
""
&$f 3
""
&$f 10
""
&$f 46
```

Comment: You can save a byte doing `1.."$args"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

<sup>-2 thanks to [@BMO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45530899#45530899)!</sup>

```
mSöd+d←dḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzf48LYU7ZRHbRNSHu5Y/P//f1MDAA)

### Explanation

```
m          map(                                              )
 S                                               <*>
  ö            (           .).    .         .
   d            fromDecimal
    +                         (++)
     d                             toDecimal
      ←                                      (+1)
       d                                            toDecimal
                                                              .
        ḣ                                                      (\n->[1..n])

mSöd+d←dḣ  map((fromDecimal.).(++).toDecimal.(+1)<*>toDecimal).(\n->[1..n])
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>103</s> <s>71</s> <s>64</s> 56 bytes

---

**Golfed** [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9NSwMxEIbv@RVD2ENCP9i2t6a7Ij0JgqAHD9ZD2I4YqLPSTHEl5LevMe62dk4v82SemTR@1njX3zbsWtrcEa@WNVioelfV4a09KkcMXVWabuOMfvr2jB/zbUu@PeD8@egYVSGD6uryppDT0EW5llLHMJmkqE3sjRDZ@vIqIBWj56316KECwi8YGIRMf2sxPcflJa4ucVHmGJM5HYi2eVd/mrMcHP1bpAf59dVQyDT1eeI1hPFt3NHDiXNPgjZ5yqqRDo0rzb0jVHJH6asiCjGyR7T7jLTpfwA)

```cs
i=>{for(int x=0;x<i;)Write($"{(x>0?$",{x}":"")}{++x}");}
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
i => {
    for( int x = 0; x < i; )
        Write( $"{( x > 0 ? $",{x}" : "")}{ ++x }" );
}
```

---

**Full code**

```cs
Action<Int32> a = i => {
    for( int x = 0; x < i; )
        Write( $"{( x > 0 ? $",{x}" : "")}{ ++x }" );
    };

Int32[]
    testCases = new Int32[] {
        1,
        2,
        3,
        10,
    };

foreach( Int32[] testCase in testCases ) {
    WriteLine( $" Input: {testCase}\nOutput:" );
    a(testCase);
    WriteLine("\n");
}
```

---

**Older versions:**

- ***v1.2, 64 bytes***

  ```cs
  i=>{for(int x=0;x<i;)Write($"{(x>0?$",{x}":"")}{++x}");}
  ```
- ***v1.1, 71 bytes***

  ```cs
  i=>{for(int x=0;x<i;)System.Console.Write($"{(x>0?$",{x}":"")}{++x}");}
  ```
- ***v1.0, 103 bytes***

  ```cs
  i=>{for(int x=0;x<i;)System.Console.Write($"{(x>0?",":"")}{x++*System.Math.Pow(10,$"{x}".Length)+x}");}
  ```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.3** - `- 8 bytes` - Removed `Console` thanks again to [raznagul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167818/concatenating-n-with-n-1/167878?noredirect=1#comment405677_167878)
- **v1.2** - `- 7 bytes` - Removed `System` thanks to [raznagul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167818/concatenating-n-with-n-1/167878?noredirect=1#comment405670_167878)
- **v1.1** - `-32 bytes`
- **v1.0** - `103 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

**Notes**

- None

Comment: The C# Interactive Compiler has static imports for `System.Console`. So you can save 15 bytes by removing it.

Comment: Right! Habit of having to _use_ them

Comment: You can also remove `Console.`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##TY9PC8IwDMXv/RSh7NDilKk3u03EkyAIXjyohzIrFiSTteKg9LPPWuefnB55L78klRlWRneLyuoa8xXa6aQECUWni9Kd64ZptNAWmWhzLfiu0VaxhDrWltk8oalrPZ1Ryr0bDILkwneCkIjZHwmEssrYpTTKQAGoHtB74KL7qnH6lZOfnP7kOIvSB3K4SMnqwt6YLxw0/i3iPfx9LSQ0pG93OwP3yfgDbu429ihwEdOSfdy@EcfXGhWjBwyvEU/IskZTX9Voq@QpWlx0Tw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
f x=[[y-1|y>1]++[y]>>=show|y<-[1..x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwjY6ulLXsKbSzjBWWzu6MtbOzrY4I7@8ptJGN9pQT68iNvZ/bmJmnoKtQko@lwIQFBRl5pUoqCikKRii8Y3Q@Mbo6g3@AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 14 bytes

```
(,&.":>:)"0@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kpBQ0dNT8nKzkpTycAhUw8kaMiVpmAExMZAbGgAAA)

Comment: `2,&.":/\i.@>:` for 13 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WSsFIR01PyUo/JlPPwc4KKKRgyJWmYATExkBsaAAA "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### ABAP, 101 bytes

Not really a golfing language, but I'm having a lot of fun with it

```
WHILE x<w.
CLEAR z.
IF x=1.
WRITE x.
ELSE.
CONCATENATE y x INTO z.
WRITE z.
ENDIF.
y=x.
x=x+1.
ENDDO.
```

W is the input term, X is the counter from 1, Y is X-1 from the second pass onward, Z is concatenated string.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
while($argv[1]--)echo" $i".++$i;
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65hoGn9vzwjMydVQyWxKL0s2jBWV1czNTkjX0lBJVNJT1tbJdP6////pgA)

Old version

```
for(;$i<$argv[1];)echo" $i".++$i;     // 33 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda l:[`n`[:n]+`n+1`for n in range(l)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKjohLyHaKi9WOyFP2zAhLb9IIU8hM0@hKDEvPVUjRzP2f0FRZl6JQpqGoYnmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 43 <s>44,46,49,53</s> bytes

```js
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,a)=>~~(a+(a+1+"")))
```

Previous versions :

```js
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,a)=>~~(a+(""+ ++a)))
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,a)=>0- -(a+(""+ ++a)))
n=>[...Array(n).keys()].map(a=>0- -(a+(""+ ++a)))
n=>[...Array(n).keys()].map(a=>parseInt(a+(""+ ++a)))
```

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy's solution (which is better than mine) to remove `.keys()`

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoAgDADQX4lOG9bo2kGh74jIURmFbaER9PX23skv5yUd99OKrlsJtoh1IxENKfEHghNdfAPMDaN1bIypa8Nth2VRyRo3irpDgL5HOvUQ31Qeyw8)

Answer (score 2):

## [yup](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/yup), 48 bytes

```
0eee0ee-0ee-*:0e#[:@]0e-{]:[:]-:#0e0~--#]:@]0e-}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qywt@P/fIDU1FYh1QVjLyiBVOdrKIdYgVbc61iraKlbXStkg1aBOV1c5FiJc@///f928/4YGAA)

### Explanation

yup only knows of a few commands. To modify data, I'll be using `0` (nilad pushing that number), `e` (natural exponentiation), and `-` (subtraction).

For example, the snippet `0e` is equal to `1`, since \$e^0=1\$.

This program is divided into two parts: initialization and iteration.

#### Initialization

```
0eee0ee-0ee-*:0e#[:@]0e-
```

`0eee` pushes \$e^e\approx15.1543\$ and `0ee` pushes \$e\approx2.7183\$. Thus, the expression `0eee0ee-0ee-` pushes:

$$e^e-e-e\approx9.7177$$

This encodes `0x10` (the linefeed), since numbers are rounded to the nearest integer before being outputted. This is our numeric separator.

The next part is to initialize the stack with data. `*:` pushes the input twice, and `0e#` outputs a `1`. `[:@]` outputs a linefeed without popping it from the stack, and `0e-` decrements the input. This handles the edge case of outputting `1` instead of `01`. Rather than handle this with a conditional, hardcoding the first entry is shorter.

### Iteration

```
{]:[:]-:#0e0~--#]:@]0e-}
```

`{...}` loops while the TOS is defined and positive. In this case, it will stop when it hits zero. Each iteration starts off with a stack like this:

```
[9.7177, input, iterator]
```

`iterator` starts at `input - 1`. `]:[:]-` calculates `input - iterator` and gives us our true iterator value. Then, `:#0e0~--#` first outputs the true iterator then the same number plus 1, where `0e0~--` encodes \$-(-n-e^0)=-(-n-1)=n+1\$. Then, `]:@]` restores the stack to its initial shape and `0e-` subtracts `1` from the iterator, continuing our loop. This repeats until `iterator` reaches `0`, at which point the loop stops and the program terminates.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda n:[f"{j or''}{j+1}"for j in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpNqTpLIb9IXb22OkvbsFYpLb9IIUshM0@hKDEvPVUjTzP2f0FRZl6JRpqGoYGBpuZ/AA)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  You can save bytes by removing the space between your string and the `for`.  Also since this is an anonymous function there is no need for `f=`, so you can save 2 bytes by removing it.

Comment: @CatWizard Thanks! But what do you mean by anonymous function? is there a way to call an anonymous function?

Comment: An anonymous function is any function that is not associated with a name.  In python the lambda keyword makes an anonymous function.  Anonymous functions can be set to variables as you did, they can also be called directly without assignment (that's what makes them anonymous) by wrapping them in parentheses e.g. `(lambda x:x+1)(6)`.  For TIO you can put `f=\ ` in the "header" section and call the function with `f`.

Comment: @CatWizard Thanks that is super helpful

Comment: How about having the condition for `1` inside the format string? [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpNqTpLIb9IXb22OkvbsFYpLb9IIUshM0@hKDEvPVUjTzP2f0FRZl6JRpqGoYGBpuZ/AA)

Comment: @JoKing Thanks! now i get to learn something more about python, I haven't seen the or operator used like that before

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ƛ‹p⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwixpvigLlw4oyKIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==)

Comment: >:( beat me by 1 byte

Answer (score 2):

## Scratch, 107 bytes

[image]

```
define(y
delete all of[x v
set[i v]to(0
repeat(y
add((join(i)((i)+(1)))-())to[x v
change[i v]by(1
end
say(x
```

I would've used `for each`, but [scratchblocks](https://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&script=) doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 13 bytes

```
{.,/$x+!2}'!:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/79aT0dfpUJb0ahWXdEKlWdo8B8A)

`!` generate the list 0 1 ... n-1

`{` `}` is a function with argument `x`

`'` applied to each

`!2` is `0 1`

`x+!2` is `x, x+1`

`$` format as strings

`,/` concatenate

`.` evaluate (convert to number)

Comment: *Strings or numbers are fine for output.* – So `.` should not be needed.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanks - the challenge has changed since I answered it

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder unfortunately, if I remove `.` there's a leading `0` in `"01"`

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
ṭ’DFḌ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzrWPGma6uD3c0aP5//9/QwMA)

```
ṭ’DFḌ)    Monadic link with argument n
     )    For each int in the range 1..n
 ’        n-1
ṭ         [n-1, n]
  D       Digits of n-1 and n
   F      Flatten into one list
    Ḍ     Convert back to an integer.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ŗ²；＋┤］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUwMTU3JUIyJXVGRjFCJXVGRjBCJXUyNTI0JXVGRjNE,i=MTA_,v=3)

Explanation:

```
{     ]  map over 1..input
 ŗ         convert to string (required as `＋` needs 1 arg to be a string to not add)
  ²;       place a 0-indexed version of the index below TOS
    +      join the two
     ┤     cast to number
```

`ŗ²×┤］` (or even `²×┤］`) would work if I didn't try to push the absolute most out of characters and didn't make `×` - reverse add - do not that when not receiving 2 strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), 11 bytes

```
=1::($-1)~$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39bQykpDRddQs07l/38jAA)

Way too long for a language that this is supposed to be easy in, guess I should have implemented unary subtract-one and add-one operators.

## Explanation

```
=1            First term in sequence is 1
  ::          Mode: for input n, output first n terms in sequence
              For each term in the sequence:
    ($-1)      Subtract 1 from the current index
         ~$    Concatenate that to the current index
```

Comment: Note current version uses `&` instead of `::`, saving 1 byte

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
2{⍎∊⍕¨⍺⍵}/0,⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v/fqPpRb9@jjq5HvVMPrXjUu@tR79ZafQOdR72b/6cpPGqboKCBW4Um16O@qWBFaSCZzab/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

*@DomHastings came up with a way to save 3 bytes*

```perl
say$i++.$i|0for 1..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIlU1tbTyWzxiAtv0jBUE/Pxu7/f0Ojf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Comment: Nice! Much shorter than my first approach using a `while` and `` $\ ``! Using yours as a base though, you can save a couple of bytes using `eval` and `x<>`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHvTixUkVXW1tPRbfGwFq9wsbu/39Dg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A "Perl 5 – Try It Online") or even [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIlXtdQQU8lvsYgLb9IwVBPz8bu/39Do3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Wait, combining the two gives 21: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFV1tbT0W3xiAtv0jBUE/Pxu7/f0Ojf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 36 bytes

```
z0w+1=*0-8*0w00+1*0-8*0-9 10z=+_M-*0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PTc1N/P@/yqBc29BWy0DXQsug3MBA2xDC1LVUMDSostWO99XVMvj/39DA4F9@QUlmfl7xf91MAA) Requires the `-i` interpreter flag.

### Explanation

```
                                                     #  i = 0
d   0            #  d0:  nop                         #  do {
i   (+ 1 =*0)    #  i0:  jump to i(![0])             #    if i {
-8  *0           #       print [0]                   #      print i
i   0            #  i1:  nop                         #    }
0   (+ 1 *0)     #       [0] = [0] + 1               #    i += 1
-8  *0           #       print [0]                   #    print i
-9  10           #       print chr(10)               #    print \n
d   =(+ _M -*0)  #  d1:  jump to d(!!(input - [0]))  #  } while (input - i != 0)
```

The Momema reference interpreter provides an "interactive mode", enabled by `-i`, which is intended to be used on the command line.

One of the features it allows is the ability to add *holes*, denoted by `_`, which effectively allow one to substitute an integer read from STDIN into an expression. This is already shorter than `*-8` (read from memory-mapped I/O location `-8`), which does the same thing without interactive mode and without displaying a prompt to STDERR.

Crucially, holes can also be *named* with a sequence of capital letters after the `_`. Evaluation of named holes is memoized. Input will be read the first time a named hole is evaluated but subsequent evaluations of a hole with the same name will reuse the input number. This means that we can use `_M` to stand in for "the input", but input will only be read on the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 56 bytes

```
func[n][prin"1 "repeat i n - 1[prin rejoin[i i + 1" "]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcgxCoAwDAXQ3VN8sopgHT2Ga8ggNoU4xBL0/FF84wutuWllGdqa7fGDXbiHORVQaNf9hsExofyN0PMyZ/t2RCGQiGTDMucL)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 56 bytes

```rust
|n|(0..n).map(|n|format!("{}{}",n,n+1).parse().unwrap())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCsMgFATQfU5hs/qfBknanUnTW3QvoiDojxhDFsazW9vZDbyZeOypGmJeWgJkuWMtTidm2KtedMHIOSH3MkBrZotephv0ueTSDzTQfUIeZNw1ID/ojM0h1vl/E6Kl5OjHxbtxZmAakavNOa2SEMtHq8U@H@vaNnNX6hc)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 48 bytes

```java
String f(int n){return--n>0?f(n)+","+n+-~n:"1";}
```

Port of [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)'s JavaScript [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167841/79343). Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoIwEEXX5SsmXbWpJbAVH1/giqVxUaGQIgykLRhD8NexoqubzM09Zxo1KdkPGpvysQ7jvTUFFK1yDi7KIMxr7q3BGipm0APy2Wo/WpQST8m5YsgF3VGBQr5xT1OaLSv5U5xXPsTUmxK6wGI/0vUGytaOwxwRsjk6OALq5yZkPAvnqrebzoQmzUIcIE2SDIQwPNQkfzmvu7gffTwEpm@RdXH4kH/XS7SsHw).

Ungolfed:

```java
String f(int n) { // recursive function taking an integer as argument and returning a String
    return --n > 0 ? f(n) // decrement n and recurse if n is still positive after
                   + "," + n // return the result of the recursive call concatenated with n and ...
                   + (- ~n) // ... n+1; writing it as -~n gives it precedence over the concatenation
                   : "1"; // if n is now 0 on the other hand, return "1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
:"@qV@VhU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30rJoTDMISwj9P9/Q0MA)

```
              % implicit input n
:             % range, push 1..n
"             % for loop:
 @            % push for loop index
 q            % decrement
 V            % convert to string (num2str)
 @            % push for loop index
 V            % convert to string (num2str)
 h            % horizontally concatenate
 U            % convert to number (str2num)
              % implicit end of for loop
              % implicit end of program, display stack contents
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Panacea](https://github.com/okx-code/Panacea), 6 bytes

```
re
D>j
```

Explanation:

```
r        Range [0.. input]
 e       Map each element with the following line
D        Duplicate
 >       Increment
  j      Join digits; multiply by ten and add
         Since this works with integers, it removes the preceding 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 5 bytes

```
õÈsiY
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9chzaVk=&input=OTk=)

---

### Explanation

```
          :Implicit input of integer U
õ         :Range [1,U]
 È        :Map each integer at index Y
  s       :  Convert to string
   iY     :  Prepend index
          :  Implicitly convert back to integer
          :Implicit output of resulting array
```

---

### Alternative

```
Ç°s+Z
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=x7BzK1o=&input=OTk=)

```
          :Implicit input of integer U
Ç         :Map each integer Z in the range [0,U)
 °        :  Postfix increment
  s       :  Convert to string
   +Z     :  Append (the now incremented) Z
          :  Implicitly convert back to integer
          :Implicit output of resulting array
```

Comment: an OEIS sequence answer with oeis in it

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/contents.htm), 20 bytes

```
".(,&":)/@(,>:)"0@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P0/B1kpBSU9DR03JSlPfQUPHzkpTycAhUw8kZciVp2AExMZAbGjwHwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 33 bytes

```forth
: f dup 1 ?do i . i 1 .r loop . ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKaSUFigYKtin5CtkKugBsaGCXpFCTn5@AZBn/d/YQCHtPwA)

#### Explanation

Loops through all numbers in range and outputs the number twice, the first with a space appended, and the second without.

This results in the first output being appended to the previous output. To fix the last case, the input is outputted so that it can be appended to the last number in the loop.

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                   \ start a new word definition
  dup 1               \ duplicate the input and put a 1 on the stack
  ?do                 \ begin counted loop from 1 to n (does nothing if 1 == n)
    i .               \ output loop index with a space appended
    i 1 .r            \ output loop index right-aligned with minimum 1 character length
  loop                \ end the loop
  .                   \ output the input we duplicated earlier
;                     \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 37 bytes

An anonymous function that takes input from STDIN and outputs to STDOUT.

```vb
Input""n
?1
For i=2TO n?i-1,"",i
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3zOvoLRESSmPy96Qyy2/SCHT1ijEXyHPPlPXUEdJSSeTyy@1ouT/f0MDAA)

-14 bytes thanks to [@ErikF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79060/erikf)

Comment: You can get it down to 31 bytes by not counting the input assignment and making use of `,` between output fields in `PRINT` to combine them: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7v6RcQGqKgpKSQ99/e0MrNP0gh09YwxF8hT9fQyj5TR0lJJ1Pb0MrPNSLk/39DAwA "Yabasic – Try It Online")

Comment: @ErikF, input *must* be taken explicitly per community rules and [cannot be taken from a predefined variable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/61846). That said I had never seen the `?n,"",m` trick - that is really quite clever.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 29 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and outputs to the console.

```vb
?1:For i=2To[A1]:?i-1 &i:Next
```

Comment: I've always wanted to use Excel VBA for one of these. I have SO much to learn!

Comment: @seadoggie01 Its a great way to get more familiar with the language - and fortunately, VBA has a very well made up [Tips Page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/tips-for-golfing-in-vba) that can help you to get started :)

Comment: @seadoggie01 oh, and if you are interested in VBA answers, I have a couple that I am really quite proud of, such as [Let's Draw Mona Lisa](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127105/61846), [Embiggen your Input](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166897/61846), and [Visualize Visual Eyes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153402/61846)

Comment: Ha! The first thing I found after this question was the Tips page :)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 29 bytes

```
[d1-d0<F]dsFx+p[npz1<G]sGz1<G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b/g/OsVQN8XAxi02pditQrsgOq@gytDGPbbYHUT9/w8A)

This is a good showing for dc because its printing capabilities are so limited, but line up perfectly with the challenge spec. Input is from the stack (and must be the only thing on the stack), output is to stdout. There's some duplication near the end I can't figure out how to get rid of without breaking the case n=1

## Explanation

```
F will be the macro [d1-d0<F]
d        copy the top of the stack
 1-      decrement
   d0<F  repeat (tail recursion) until a 0 is on top

G will be the macro [npz1<G]
n        print the top (pop, but no newline)
 p       print the new top (newline, but no pop)
  z1<G   repeat (tail recursion) until only one number is on the stack

Full program (example input: 4)
[d1-d0<F]dsFx      Store F and run it: new stack is 0 1 2 3 4
+                  Drop the zero (can't just recurse to 1, or n=1 breaks)
p                  Print (no pop) the '1': stack is 1 2 3 4
[npz1<G]sG        Store G
z1<G               Run G if there's more than one number on the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 34 bytes

```
sj1psi[lid1+dsiZAr^*li+pzlj>M]dsMx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2jwvzjLsKA4MzonM8VQO6U4M8qxKE4rJ1O7oCony843NqXYt@L/fwA)

Completely different (and less golfy, unfortunately) approach than Sophia's `dc` answer. I juggle a lot of register activity here that I wish I could cut down, seems the likeliest way to golf a couple of bytes. Expects input as the sole stack entry.

`sj1psi` stores the input into register `j`, prints the initial 1, and stores 1 in register `i`. Macro `M` duplicates `i`, increments it, and then multiplies it by 10 to the power of however many digits the incremented value has (`ZAr^*`). Fetches the newly incremented version, and adds the two together. Compares register `j` to the number of entries on the stack, and runs until they match.

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB <strike>45</strike> 63 bytes

```
@(j)eval('for a=0:j-1;disp([num2str(a)*a/a,num2str(a+1)]);end')
```

Somewhat ugly `*a/a` in order to avoid printing leading zero for the first element

Fixed by wrapping into `disp` and anonymous function

Comment: You can't assume the input is predefined as a variable unfortunately. You have to do `j=input('');` or create a function. Anyway, +1, as I'm assuming you'll fix it. Anonymous function with `eval` is often shortest when loops are involved.

Comment: @StewieGriffin thanks for advice, i am still learning ways around golfing

Comment: @StewieGriffin by anonymous function + eval you mean something like `f = @(j) eval('for ..... end')` ?

Comment: Yes :-) you don't need to include `f=` in the byte count, since the function can be used unnamed like: `ans(6)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 93 bytes

```d
import std.math;_[]f(_)(_ n){_[]k;foreach(i;0..n)k~=++i+10^^(cast(_)i--.log10+1)*i;return k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzNCoMwEITveYo9JlVD0h6XPomoBH/qoiYlbtuD2Fe36aHQw8AM3/B1x0HLPUSGlTu9OB6xKatBNko24NWWxoRDiL1rR0lotPZqel@zjDJr6lq2buV0pqLQc7hZk1l1Iow9P6KHCfd/ewoFFM9AHSyOvFSwiZ@bEUqbwzmHSw7WpGaqL2c96Fck7mePYhf78QE)

I couldn't find a nice (short) solution that evades an `import`, and this was the shortest of the bunch.

Comment: You can save two bytes by making `auto ` be `_[]`

Comment: @Zacharý Good point!

Comment: WOuldn't it just be easier to do `std.conv` trickery?

Answer (score 1):

## QBasic, <s>60</s> 53 bytes

```
INPUT n
?1
FOR i=2TO n
?STR$(i-1)MID$(STR$(i),2)
NEXT
```

<s>A math-based solution, because converting numbers to strings in QBasic is a lot more complicated than it ought to be.</s> Nope, strings are still shorter, you just have to special-case the first item. The problem with `STR$(i)` is that it adds a space to the start of positive numbers, so we take all but the first character by using `MID$`. Other than that, it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

## [DC](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 33 bytes

```
si[lidZAr^spd1-dsilp*+li0<d]dsdxf
```

Explanation

```
si[lidZAr^spd1-dsilp*+li0<d]dsdxf  Whole program.
si                                 Save the value on the stack to the i register.
  [                        ]dsdx   Create a macro, duplicate it, store it in the d register, and execute it.
   li                              Put the value from the i register on the stack.
     dZ                            Duplicate the top value, and change it to the number of digits it has.
       Ar                          Push 10 on the stack, and reverse the top two values.
         ^sp                       Do 10^x, and store it in the p register.
            d1-                    Duplicate the top value, and subtract 1 from it.
               dsi                 Duplicate the top value, and store it in the i register.
                  lp*+             Put the value from the p register on the stack, and multiply it by the the value we just put in the i register. Then, add the top two values together.
                      li0<d        Put the value from the i register and then 0 on the stack. If 0 < li, then we run the d macro again.
                                f  Print the stack.
```

Input is the number of numbers to be generated, on the stack.

Output is printed.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks! I've been lurking for a while, figured I'd finally give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 48 bytes

```
{"1, "+(2..it).map{"$it${it+1}"}.joinToString()}
```

Yes I know, I could save 1 more byte by removing the blank behind the first comma, but it looks nicer with it :-)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsMgEETv@YpFPChpBT1KG@ix5/YHvBi2NZtgtoUifrsVMrd5w2PeKyek9g0JovWg7sT6PD04I81whVaEPYEYlTMGWZslbEVIZFmQR1tFNa8V6bkegtK1xQ/BEpBUyPPu4ZZz@F2OedJQBujZeuNESlC/sM53JEu0yjpdhR5q@wM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 310 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Ford,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Ford]Ford:Listen tothy.Ajax:You cat.Open heart.[Exit Ajax][Enter Page]Scene V:.Ford:Am I worse Ajax?If notlet usScene X.You be twice the sum ofa cat a big big cat.Speak thy.Page:Open heart.You be the sum ofyou a cat.Open heart.Let usScene V.Scene X:.[Exeunt]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBC4JAEIX/yvwAWeq6l/BQIAQFQRjhYbJJLdsVd0T79bazVkiHHZbHm/c9xjX1OEYqvuMQqY1tr5HaY0FeyRkSrQ45GZLPeW2YWhAjoLmCeDMZels5JgNsuXyFIH2yHeTIatd4vSRs2a8PFYft7JMkmGyKP@qA1vETEuht6yg4V8kNjOWaGDo3OVMl2RcC7qvcz5LAdU@wNxQgIFyqIjzBHxrCB0grYelZm2/Ib/3lBfzvvJ2Bj59LpHKJgTrD2TguF28)

Comment: If you don't mind ending in an error, you can get rid of scene X for [293 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY7NCsIwEIRfZR@gBL3mIj0oFASFQkGkh21d22qblGaL9ulrNv5QPGQJw8x84/p2niMV3/AZqZ0dLpE6YkVeKRkSrdKSDMnnvDVMA4gR0FxAvLkcvW8ckwG2XE@hSJ/sCCWyOvRerwkH9vFnwyGdf5oEk7/rMx3QOu4ggYcdHAXnJrmCsdwSw@g@Q5R0FwT8aEp/awI3dmCvKEBAKJoqPMGnPeEdZJWw9GLNt@QXn7yA/5v3C3Cm5nm9egE)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>8 6 5</s> 4 bytes

```
{└§p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/60ZQph5YX/P9vaAAA)

Outputs a newline separated series.

#### Explanation:

```
{└§p
{       Start a loop over the range(0, input)
 └      Push the top of stack (implicitly the index of the loop) + 1
  §     Concatenate the two (this removes leading 0s)
   p    And print the value
```

Comment: Really nice solution! Splitting the printing into two different loop iterations was really clever! I saw that you used the "push n+1 without popping" operator too, it worked really well for this task.

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 33 bytes

```
/01iR1-:0)?;{1+:
\$1<\}$q}:+1{$ '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/fwDAzyFDXykDT3rraUNuKK0bF0CamVqWw1krbsFpFQf3/fwA)

Uncompressing the entry sequence and moving the reflectors to the other side:

```
>1$01iR1-:0)?;{1+:\
      \}$q}:+1{$ '/
```

Entry sequence (`>1$01i`) is fairly straight forward. Push and print `1`, push `0`, push `1`, read input and push it to the top of the stack.

At `R` we enter the program's main loop (unrolled with directional control characters removed):

```
1-:0)?;{1+:' ${1+:}q$}
```

At this point the stack is `[0,1,i]` where `i` is the input value.

The loop subtracts 1 from the input value (`1-`), compares it to greater than 0 (if true, skip terminator, else terminate; `:0)?;`).

Then a series of stack manipulations (`{1+:{1+:}`) and increments to result in `[2,(i-1),1,1,2]` as well as printing a space (`' $`). `q` then concats the top two items on the stack, which is then printed (giving `12` in the output stream).

Finally the stack is rotated once more, leaving `[1,2,(i-1)]` as the input to the next loop iteration.

### Bonus challenge: using two IPs? 40 bytes

```
>1$0iR1-:0)?;1{+:' \
> F1iU }$~?=am$?=9m/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/OUMUgM8hQ18pA097asFrbSl0hhstOwc0wM1ShVqXO3jYxV8Xe1jJX//9/EwUTAA)

As there's no way to clone the input to a second instruction pointer (I have thought about stack cloning, so this may be possible in the future, but the spec for it would be difficult to implement), we have to read it from the input stream twice.

Flow results in the second pointer being a step behind the first (avoiding merging) and the `F`izzle lets us distinguish the two IPs, letting one print a space and the other discards it. I can't figure out a shorter way of performing this check.

However if it allowable to print *two* spaces as a separator it can be reduced to *this* (30 bytes):

```
>1$0iR1-:0)?;1\
> F1iU}$:+{$ '/

input: 4 4
output: 1  12  23  34
```

But this is an admittedly dubious answer due to how it has to take input, but 3 bytes shorter than the single IP answer, which is interesting.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/OUMUgM8hQ18pA097aMIbLTsHNMDO0VsVKu1pFQV3//38TBRMA)

#### Update: Stack transfer

Getting the two pointers to enter the `T` command in the right execution order is a *huge* pain. The remaining two spaces in this program can't be removed, as it messes with the timing, but it avoids having to supply the input value twice. Prints 2 spaces between each entry in the sequence (35 bytes).

```
>1$0y TR1-:0)?;1\
 >1i:1/U}$:+{$ '/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/OUMWgUiEkyFDXykDT3towhkvBzjDTylA/tFbFSrtaRUFd//9/EwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), <s>102</s> 94 bytes

```
1 INPUT N:FOR I=0 TO N-1:IF I>0 THEN PRINT MID$(STR$(I),2);
2 PRINT MID$(STR$(I+1),2);" ";:NEXT
```

Output:

```
? 3
1 12 23

? 10
1 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 910

? 16
1 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 910 1011 1112 1213 1314 1415 1516
```

Could have been much cleaner, but the STR$(n) number-to-string conversion function returns with a leading space that had to be dealt with.

Turns out the variable for NEXT and the trailing PRINT are not needed, saving 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## jq, <s>30</s> 27 characters

```
1,(range(1;.)|"\(.)\(.+1)")
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.1$ jq -r '1,(range(1;.)|"\(.)\(.+1)")' <<< 5
1
12
23
34
45
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/99QR6MoMS89VcPQWk@zRilGQ08TiLUNNZU0gZKm//ILSjLz84r/6xYBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
ln1-:?!;aoln:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PyfPUNfKXtE6MT8nz@r///@6ZQrGAA)

We take in the input as a command line argument.

Thanks to @jo king for 2 byte loss (noticing the input loop value could be used as stack length.

Explanation (simple):

```
ln1-:?!;aoln:
ln              : Add the length of the stack to the stack and print.
   1-:?!;       : Take 1 off the input loop and check if zero, if 0, end.
         ao     : Print new line
           ln:  : Add the length of the stack to the stack, print and duplicate the input loop.
```

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PyfPUNfKXtE6MT8nz@r///@6ZQrGAA). Also note that you don't have to count flags as bytes anymore

Comment: @JoKing I know I haven't been super active recently but when was that change? Also that is a nice change to mine, didn't even think about using the input as the length.

Comment: [Herr's the meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/76162) discussion.

Comment: @JoKing Perfect, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)

```ruby
:*|:*&(-[I,:+&1]|:join|Z)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWO620aqy01DR0oz11rLTVDGNrrLLyM_NqojQh8ssLFNyijQxiIbwFCyA0AA)

### Explanation

```ruby
:* |              # Range 0..n-1, then
:* & (            # map with ...
  -[I, :+ & 1] |  #   [m, m+1] (I is identity), then
  :join |         #   join, then
  Z               #   convert to int (for special case "01")
)
```

Comment: `:join` in place of `~:*&""` should be -1

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```
import sugar,sequtils,math
s(x=>toSeq(1..x).map y=>(y-1)*10^len($y)+y)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wU3DgqL8ZIVijTQrBTBLo8JKITOvRNNKoTi1MBrIitVUsOVSUEhNzshXSNMwNNBcWlqSpmtx0y0ztyC_qEShuDQ9sUgHqLi0JDOnWCc3sSSDq1ijwtauJD84tVDDUE-vQlMvN7FAodLWTqNS11BTy9AgLic1T0OlUlO7EmraAigFpQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ʀ¨pJ⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJB4biLIiwiIiwiyoDCqHBK4oyKIiwiIiwiNFxuMTAiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
ʀ¨pJ⌊
ʀ     # Inclusive zero range
 ¨p   # each overlapping pair
   J  # merge
    ⌊ # floor
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```
proc(x:any)=
 echo 1;for i in(2..x):echo i-1,i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/V9QlJ@sUKyRZqUAZmlUWClk5pVoairYcikopCkYGhj8L9YASQFlEvMqNYHCqckZ@QqG1mn5RQqZQMUaRnp6FZpWYNFMXUOdTM3//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 76 bytes

```
listen to N
X's 0
while N-X
let S be X
let X be+1
let S be+""+X
cast S
say S
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

```
listen to N       :Read input string into variable N
X's 0             :Initialise X as 0
while N-X         :While X is less than N
let S be X        :  Assign X to S
let X be+1        :  Increment X
let S be+""+X     :  Append X to S
cast S            :  Cast S to an integer
say S             :  Output S
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```julia
!n=["1";2:n.|>i->"$(i-1)$i"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPNlrJUMnayCpPr8YuU9dOSUUjU9dQUyVTKfa/Q3FGfrmCoiEXlGEEYxjDGIYG/wE)

based on the answer by [Sundar R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8774/sundar-r)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 59 bytes

```
proc C n {puts [incr i]
time {puts $i[incr i]} [expr $n-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcsxCoAgFAbgvVP8g0MNQdYRPIY5hDgI@nqYgSCe3RZbP/iyDb1zui0UCJXf/EB7sgneTNlHN0z4Xxu0K5wgaJWm9RAvRkGV2HFAbm2Ek9QsyjIpiNL6Bw)

PS: I will golf it more later!

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>57</strike> 55 bytes

```hs
f n=read<$>zipWith((.show).(++).show)[0..][1..n]::[Int]
```

A function which takes a number and returns a list.

*EDIT: -2 Bytes thanks to [Cat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/cat-wizard)*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7YoNTHFRsWuKrMgPLMkQ0NDrzgjv1xTT0NbWxPCjDbQ04uNNtTTy4u1sor2zCuJ/Z@bmJlnm5LPpaCQV5qrYKOrkJ5a4pOZlwoUKCjKzCtRUFFIU9AAmQxWYGWlANSm@d/QwAAA)

Comment: My answer has been outdone by @Doorknob, go check out his.

Comment: You can save a byte by using `[0..n]` and `[1..n]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

## RAD, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
(⊢(⊢+⊣×10*1+∘⌊10⍟⊢)1+⊢)¨0,⍳
```

[Repository](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad/src)

Must be called like: `((⊢(⊢+⊣×10*1+∘⌊10⍟⊢)1+⊢)¨0,⍳) <value>`, as I broke assignment of functions when I implemented shy results.

**Note:** this should also work in Dyalog APL, and due to that: -1 byte thanks to @Adám!

The `⍳` can either be the APL symbol or the greek one if run in RAD, but must be the APL version ifran in Dyalog APL

Comment: `+(⌊10⍟⊢)` → `+∘⌊10⍟⊢`

Comment: Thanks! Outgolfed in my own language ... somewhat, but this is also APL code, so not really.

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
{{_)s+si}%}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1flPm/ujpes1i7OLNWtfZ/XcJ/QwMDAwA)

Comment: [`{_)s+si}%p`](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1flPm/Ol6zWLs4s1a14P9/QwMDAwA) 
<s>saves one byte</s> (nevermind, it's not allowed since it's not a function)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda i:[1]+[`x`+`x+1`for x in range(1,i)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHTKtowVjs6oSJBO6FC2zAhLb9IoUIhM0@hKDEvPVXDUCdTM/Z/QVFmXolCmoaRgeZ/AA)

First element is an integer, the rest are strings.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5, 29 bytes

```perl
say"@{[1,map$_-1 .$_,2..<>]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 54 bytes

Uses space as seperator character.

```cs
n=>{var r="";for(;n-->1;)r=" "+n+(n+1)+r;return"1"+r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcyxCsIwEAbgvU8RMiXEFqNjbBfBSUFwcA4xlUC9wCUtSOmzx6jg4JR/Ov777kyoTTDJDDoEcq7miuSEqKMzZPLuRk7aAeOf@rt85/IM0T6awwhm5yCu8gU6uHekJ22CtpsnjQRbSlXvkSmo604qngtCBQgGQnKBCm0cEaikeV6Sqv7f7z0EP9jmii7aowPLeiY5VyVuU@i2hU6ui@FPLtWSXg)

**Ungolfed full code:**

```cs
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Func<int, string> f =
            n =>
            {
                var r = "";        //Declare variable for the result
                for (; n--> 1;)    //Loop until n is 1

                    r =            //Set the result to:
                        " " +      //Seperator +
                        n +        //Value of n as string
                        (n + 1) +  //Value of n + 1 as string
                        r;         //Previous content of the result

                return "1" + r;    //Return 1 (first item) + the result.
            }
            ;

        System.Console.WriteLine(f(1));
        System.Console.WriteLine(f(2));
        System.Console.WriteLine(f(3));
        System.Console.WriteLine(f(10));
        System.Console.WriteLine(f(100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 46 bytes

If you are allowed to have some `using static` directives in the top whose bytes do not count:

```cs
n=>1+Concat(Range(1,n-1).Select(x=>","+x+++x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY6xDoIwEED3fkXj1KZArI4Ii9FJEyODc60naQJHbIvBGL4dSwKbCeu7d@9Ou1g7PbTOYEmdV95oWnychzopvA0wJf9mJ4Ov5IBtDVbdK0gJmea6Us7Ri21Kq2rynfG7MQ96VgYZD3CKHFvUO4M@CvHxVE6fgdBswCyXYt@gVp5dFZbAZISx5EkBFWjPuixfRSvRCSE6zod0DoYV11SQ3KzxEF4ENgaZ5HxJ2Swr22VFrkenJ/3wAw)

Will explode if input `n` is `0`.

It is interesting that, while the C# rules say `","+x+++x` means `( "," + (x++) ) + x`, if it had meant `( "," + x ) + (++x)` instead, the program would still work!

Comment: The `using` Statements should be included in the byte count. [See this meta questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8287/on-scoring-imported-functions). Only `using` statements that are automatically included by the environment do not need to be counted. (Eg. TIO automatically adds `using static System.Console` for Visual C# Interactive Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 54 bytes

```clj
#(reduce(fn[a n](conj a(str n(inc n))))[1](range 1 %))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcmxDoIwFAXQX7mJMb4ualf9AiYXN8LQlCdCmlvyaEP8@spZT0x5qaZNVptZEiHtJKZjjSof9gEcJGYuCLIVA2VmBN2h94NY4KTwODvX/N05PNFxrQVfNb2iw5h5KTANKf0w6RF5R8mom@LdvfC4tT8)

Just a reduction over a range between 1 (inclusive) and n (exclusive).

```clj
(defn concat-n-n+1 [n]
  (reduce (fn [acc m]
            (conj acc (str m (inc m))))
          [1]
          (range 1 n)))
```

The first element of the list is a number, the rest are strings. This seems to be allowed by the spec.

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 12 bytes

**Solution:**

```
,/'$1,2':1+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0dfXcVQx0jdylBb0dDg/38A)

**Examples:**

```
,/'$1,2':1+!1
,,"1"
,/'$1,2':1+!2
(,"1"
 "12")
,/'$1,2':1+!3
(,"1"
 "12"
 "23")
,/'$1,2':1+!10 
(,"1"
 "12"
 "23"
 "34"
 "45"
 "56"
 "67"
 "78"
 "89"
 "910")
```

**Explanation:**

```
,/'$1,2':1+! / the solution
           ! / range 0..n
         1+  / add 1
      2':    / sliding window of 2
    1,       / prepend 1
   $         / convert to strings
,/'          / flatten each
```

Answer (score 0):

### C Sharp 51 bytes

```
n=>new int[n].Select((_,o)=>int.Parse($"{o}{o+1}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 15 bytes

```
{N!_'-~_}=>Iota
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@7/aTzFeXbcuvtbWzjO/JPG/X2pqSnG0SkFBcnosV0BRZl5JSGpxiXNicWpxdJqOQrShjoKRjoKxjoKhAZBlEBv7HwA)

### Explanation

```
{N!_'-~_}=>Iota
{       }=>        map the inside function:
           Iota    (over each number k from 0 to n-1)
    '              array concatenate:
   _               k
     -~_           k+1
 N!                convert [k, k + 1] to an integer (concatenates and returns a number)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rutger](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Rutger), 108 bytes

```
x=$Input;
f=For[$x];
f=f[@i];
f=f[{p=Subtract[$i];r=Concat[Str[p[1]]];Print[Integer[r[Str[$i]]]];}];
Do[$f];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCsIwDIbvfYox@gBWvZWAoAi7DXYMPczZykDaEjIYDJ99pjovnpL835cQmvjhaX2mlCuoronw6KzaxlLwNMa7n//CZZ1BNzFPbFWAsqaLEiCIvzVLhm66MfUDo5aQ4Jzi0DN2TJjROOdsS2NkbCJ7@QLpg8Qt6CVnLgl1cHb9ajUA1JL@SPlEoFF7dVBm9wY)

### Ungolfed

```
input = $Input;
for = For[$input];
for = for[@index];

for = for[{
    dec = Subtract[$index];
    ret = Concat[Str[dec[1]]];
    Print[Integer[ret[Str[$index]]]];
}];

Do[$for];
```

The basic concept of Rutger is the lack of multi-adic commands: every command takes a single argument, and if the command needs multiple argument, each new call returns a curried function.

First, we take evaluated input and store it in \$x\$. We then create a `For` object, a tri-adic command. The first two calls create a variable \$f\$, that will loop \$x\$ times, using the iteration variable \$i\$, starting at \$i := 1\$. The third call indicates the code to be run:

```
{p=Subtract[$i];r=Concat[Str[p[1]]];Print[Integer[r[Str[$i]]]];}
```

This creates a block of code containing 3 statements. Our first two are variable assignments. First, we create a curried function `Subtract[$i]`, which prepares to subtract a value from \$i\$. This curried function is saved in the \$p\$ variable. Next, we create a second curried variable, \$r\$, which starts by calling `p[1]`, subtracting \$1\$ from \$i\$. We then convert \$i-1\$ to a string and pass it as the first argument to the `Concat` function. Finally, we convert \$i\$ to a string, concatenate it to \$str(i - 1)\$ and convert it to an integer to reomve the leading \$0\$ when \$i = 1\$. This is then printed.

The last line, `Do[$f];`, runs the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

**C, 39 bytes**

```
x(n){n&&x(n-1);printf("%d%d, ",n,n+1);}
```

eliminated the ternary conditional and shaved off 3 bytes.

Comment: `Leaving the main function out` is allowed per [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/73111), since it often is shorter than a full program in C submissions often only implement a function. If you want to leave your submission as a whole program, I suggest removing the two spaces in `"%d%d, "` and `char **n`. `n==0?:x(n-1);` can also be `n&&x(n-1);`.

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), <s>23</s> 20 bytes

Saved a handful of bytes by using better named variables.

```lua
range(0,n)//(x..y|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/78oMS89VcNAJ09TX1@jQk@vssZA8////8YA)

Answer (score 0):

## RAD, 72 bytes

```
0,(⊢+10×⊣)⍁¨∊¨(⌽∘⌊(⊢|⍨10*(⍳(1+∘⌊10⍟⊢)))÷10*1-⍨(⍳(1+∘⌊10⍟⊢)))¨¨(⊢,1+⊢)¨⍳⎕
```

[Link to repository](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad/src)

I wanted to try to see if I could do it in a "non-mathematical" way by splitting a number up into its digits.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```ruby
->n{$><<i||=p(1);p(i+=1)<n&&redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsXOxiazpsa2QMNQ07pAI1Pb1lDTJk9NrSg1Jb/2f1q0oUHsfwA)

Pseudocode:

```ruby
loop
  if i is undefined
    set i to 1
    print 1
    print newline
  end if
  print i
  increment i by 1
  print i
  print newline
  if i >= n
    break and return
  end if
end loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 52 bytes

I tried my best. Not yet familiar with this golfing thing.

```
def a(n):
    for e in range(n):
        print int(`e`+`e+1`)
```

The `int()` removes the leading zero in the first output, as specified in the rules.

Comment: Changing this to an anonymous lambda function returning a list of numbers gets it down to [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjozr0QjITVBOyFV2zBBMy2/SCFVITNPoSgxLz1VI08z9n9BEVCJQpqGoYHmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Twig, 72 bytes

Twig is very verbose, causing some issues when trying to reduce the length.

```
{%macro f(a)%}{%for i in 1..a%}{{o~i}}
{%set o=i%}{%endfor%}{%endmacro%}
```

This requires that "strict variables" is disabled (default).

---

### How to use?

Simply import the macro and call it:

```
{% import "fn.twig" as fn %}
{{ fn.f(<number>) }}
```

You can test it on https://twigfiddle.com/lah1a5

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 35 bytes

```hs
f n="1":map(show.(-1+)<>show)[2..n]
```

[Try it online! <sup>1</sup>](https://tio.run/##FcbBCgIhEAbgV/nZkxJJdgzdS117gugwsG4rrTOiAz2@1eGDb6P@Tvs@cqnSFDdScndhyQsMTJgt7FjBcfLTpVA1fZOPM0d/sGH@3z7OzvFzFMqMiNoyKxzWn5ZoQQwBr6RXYU2sffjTFw)

### Explanation / Ungolfed

The operator `(<>)` is the addition of Semigroups, in case of the Semigroup `a -> b` (where `b` needs to be a Semigroup) it is defined as:

```hs
(f <> g) = \x-> f x <> g x
```

And in case of the Semigroup `String` it is the same as concatenation, so the code becomes:

```hs
f n = "1" : map (\x-> show (x-1) ++ show x) [2..n]
```

---

<sub>1 (imports `(<>)` since it's not part of the Prelude in GHC 8.2.2)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

### TI-Basic, 22 bytes

```
:seq(A,A,1,Ans
:Ans+(Ans-1)10^(1+int(log(Ans
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 56 bytes

```
echo 1;for i in $(seq $(($1-1)));do echo $i$((i+1));done
```

A pretty naive approach.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 62 bytes

```lua
loadstring't={1}for i=2,(...)do t[#t+1]=(i-1)..i end return t'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJBCgIxDADArwQ9bIJrsN77EvFQt60ESgMxiwfx7dFhxl6i5xha6stN5nPx/EnfrgaSrysyM1UFvx39lO4Z5ZyIWaDNCtZ8twm@hCi/Tbyhl8dovOnciiNAx3QhgBUO/0QRPw)

---

#### Explanation

This is an anonymous function.

```lua
t={1} -- initializes the return table, with the number 1 already in it
for i = 2, (...) do -- loop from 2 to the number of the input
                  -- (this is actual code, ... gets the arguments of the program/function
  t[#t+1] = (i-1)..i -- append to the table i-1 concatenated with i
end
return t -- returns the table
```

Comment: You can do `[i]` instead of `[#t+1]` and remove the brackets around `...`. [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcJBCoQwDADArwQvtuAG670vEQ9d20qgNBAjHhbfnnWYdiWr0RqnfKpQP0aNv/BUFqC4TIiYGXSlLTr6BI9IUHoGKXpJBx2NGG8hLU7TtxXcue9JXXVh9hMMb@/N/g "Lua – Try It Online")

Comment: Or it's shorter to have a full program. [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0TDUDMtv0gh09ZIR09PLyVfASKqkalrqKmnl6mZmpfy//9/QwMA "Lua – Try It Online")

Comment: About the first comment: yeah, I didn't pay attention :/
About the second: can I?! Hahah I thought the output had to be in the same line, as shown in the "question", that's why I did all of that table thing.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 43 bytes

```swift
print(1);(1..<n).map{print("\($0)\($0+1)")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQp2Cr4JlXolGUmpjik5mXqqGpqKn4v6AoEyhmqGmtYainZ5OnqZebWFANEVSK0VAx0AQR2oaaSpq1//8bAwA)

`n` is the input of the program

Answer (score 0):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether), 15 bytes

```
I(iWi1+W+WP?!i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tPLclILfr/31MjMzzTUDtcOzw@wF4xU/P/f0MDAA)

### Explanation

```
I(             ) - Loop until the top of the stack equals the input
  iW             - Push i and convert it to a string
    i1+W         - Add one to i and convert to string
        +        - Concatenate two strings
         WP      - Convert string to a number and print it
           ?     - Print a newline
            !i   - Increment i
```

Answer (score 0):

**VBA (Excel), 31 bytes**

using immediate window and Cell `[A1]` as input

`for x=1to[a1]:?int(x-1 &x):next`

Answer (score 0):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 68 bytes

```
RrEEEEEREeErREEREEEEEREErEEEEEeEErEEEereEEreeErEEEEEeeEReerREEREeRee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#--iR@F-jFS6!oMIS2/@FD/)

Previous code has errors when giving input 0, so this is fixed!

Explanation:

```
# Preparation

  RrEEEEE # Stack r: [0, 1]
  
  REeE # Stack R: [input]

# Loop

  rREE # create label input (r flag: skip until REe)

    REEEEE # increment input (loop preparation)
    REE # create label input

      rEEEEEeEE # join all
      rEEEe # move r pointer to last
      reEE # output as int
      reeE # output newline "\n"
      rEEEEEeeE # increment all

    Ree # repeat if input != last content of stack
    rREE # create label input + 1 (r flag: skip until REe)
    REe # stop skipping commands

  Ree # if not 0, go to loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

I know there are plenty of shorter answers already.

```python
a=0
exec"print`a`[:a]+`a+1`;a+=1;"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9HWgCu1IjVZqaAoM68kITEh2ioxVjshUdswwTpR29bQWkkrM6@gtERD8/9/QwMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org),  <s>43</s>  41 bytes

```
{(1..it).mapIndexed{i,v->"$i$v".toInt()}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BCoMwEETvfsUSPOxCDS29iab0KHjrFwRMZamuElNpEb89DQXnNsxj3msKA0t8vgVGy4LW90sJd@/tt3oEz9Ibgi2DlNUOkDZsJBAUBlpeQpWKgTpueNGaA@nRzo107uO6jU9rYVTO@ap0mBKItO/xeBKoAb2zXcvikOBWgjorOsi/cU7@gAsKUbbH6w8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Microscript II](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Microscript-II), 16 bytes

```
1vsN-s{lPps1+v}*
```

Output is newline-separated.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 11 bytes

```
IFLL?nLPN|;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39PNx8c@zyfAr8b6/39DAwMA)

Explanation:

```
IFLL?nLPN|;

I           //Take a number as input
 F          //Loop as many times as the input specified
  LL        //  Push the loop counter twice to the stack (same as L:)
    ?n      //  Check wether the count is zero, if not print the counter as the first digit
      LP    //  Push the loop counter and add 1
        N   //  Output the next digits of the number with nl
         |; //Exit code
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
f(n)=>List.generate(n,(e)=>e<1?1:'$e${e+1}');
```

-1 byte by replacing `e==0` by `e<1`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/P00jT9PWziezuEQvPTUvtSixJFUjT0cjFSiYamNob2ilrpKqUp2qbVirrmn9vyw/M0UhNzEzT0OzmouzoCgzr0QjTcNQU9MajaegAOcbofGN0fiGBiCB2v8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 29 bytes

```
;=n+0P;=i 0W>n iO+0++""i=i+1i
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PW4rMFA7PWkgMFc+biBpTyswKytcIlwiaT1pKzFpIiwiMTAiLCIyLjAiXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 42 characters

```
*=@repeat{*;${n;}@set{n;@add{${n;};1}}$n }
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.1$ gema '*=@repeat{*;${n;}@set{n;@add{${n;};1}}$n }' <<< 5
1 12 23 34 45
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/X8vWoSi1IDWxpFrLWqU6z7rWoTi1BEg7JKakVIMFrA1ra1XyFGr//zc0BQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 12 bytes

```
Rrp[:u`u' o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@oqCDaqjShVF0hP/b/f1NTAA)

This is pretty brute force, but short enough to warrant a post I think...

```
R            - generate an inclusive rangefrom "0" to the STDIN number
 rp          - reverse the stack, delete the "0"
   [       ] - for each number on the stack...
    :u       - duplicate number, print it
      `u     - increment the number, print it
        ' o  - print a space
```

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 26 bytes

```
a=$1{for(;a;a--)$a=a a+1}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/0VbFsDotv0jDOtE6UVdXUyXRNlEhUduw1vD/f2MTAA)

Turns out that a version in AWK is pretty short too, so here's that one...

```
a=$1                       - stash the number we want
    {                   }  - code always runs if STDIN>0
     for(;a;a--)           - loop for N, N-1, N-2, ... 1
                $a=a a+1   - set positional var to N appended w/ N+1
                         1 - print all the positional vars we just set
```

This really just abuses the fact that AWK will reset the positional variable count if you set them to a value.  And it uses a "truthy" condition with no associated code block to print them all.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 122 bytes, using string operations

```go
import(."strconv";."fmt")
func f(n int)(o[]int){for i:=0;i<n;i++{k,_:=Atoi(Sprintf("%d%d",i,i+1))
o=append(o,k)}
return o}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY49CsJAEIX7nGJZEGZJlEQbMaawsxQsRSQk2TDEzCzrxsLgSWyCYOeFvI1GBbF6fPD-LteSu7tJsyotC1GnSLfG6eH0ccLasHUwkgdnM6ajjEdS104qTzeUCQ0kkJwC3mx7bTVbgbMkjHFOMfp-WwW7WbJwjLA29mXRIAf5IJcBBuhHSnmcpMYUlAMHlTp7tnCNJcHn74Ple6e_BEq03qrv2BNo6LM_Gv_R5I-i8IXfvq776BM)

## [Go](https://go.dev), 125 bytes, using formula

```go
import."math"
func f(n int)(o[]int){for i:=0;i<n;i++{o=append(o,i*int(Pow10(1+int(Floor(Log10(float64(i)+1)))))+i+1)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VU9BasNADLz7FYtPsretvUkIpamvPfXge0hgSbyOqC2ZZU0Pxi_pxRTyiDwlv8naTqERCGmGGUb6-S15uDT68KXLQtQaKcC6YeteQlO78Nw68_x67f-4WrtTGJiWDsIACSQXAW934-wMW4FvWbrBd9qglB1numkKOgI_YewlkPO3SkHJcf-omC18cukZU7F26xVgJFU0lkS_9IEtXGupvx9BSSIoVukelJDCTP6KS6DJ5CnyrebjxkcgEl2QWx9WERjwon9o8YCWD0ilHt5Th2GeNw)

Uses the formula \$a(n) = n\cdot10^{1 + \lfloor\log_{10}(n+1))\rfloor} + n + 1\$ for \$n \ge 0\$.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 29 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 3.625 bytes

```
ʀzṅ⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiyoB64bmF4oyKIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==)

### Explained

```
ɾzṅ
ɾ   # range [1, input]
 z  # overlapping pairs (equivalent to 2l)
  ṅ # concatenate each pair into a single string
```

Comment: This appears to consistently omit the first '1' required for each output sequence...

Comment: ([naffetS's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252871/95126) seems to get 3.375 bytes, though...)

Answer (score 0):

## SAS

Input is passed by:

```
%let n=123;
```

## 4GL - 38

```
data;
do i=1to &n;x=cats(i-1,i)+0;put x;end;
run;
```

The `data;` and `run;` are obligatory for every 4GL data step, so the code effectively doing the job is in line 2.

## Macrolanguage - 44

```
%macro 
m(n,x);%do i=1%to&n;%put&x&i;%let x=&i;%end;
%mend;
```

The `%macro` and `%mend;` are obligatory for every Macroprogram, so the code effectively doing the job is in line 2.

To run macro execute:

```
%m(&n)
```